# Rails sql query with dynamic attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Say I have an `ActiveRecord` object that contains a `quantity` and a `price` stored in the database.

I have defined a accessor for the total_price:

```
def total_price
 quantity * price
end
```

Now what if I want to use this dynamic "attribute" in multiple `ActiveRecord` query contexts? I might to sum on it, compute average, for multiple scope, etc.

What would be the best practices so that I don't have to repeat this `quantity * price` with `ActiveRecord` and if I don't want to denormalize by writing it in DB?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `attr_accessor` to create a virtual attribute, like this: `attr_accessor :total_price`

Comment: That might not have been very clear in the question but I am trying to use this attribute in active records queries. Adding an attribute accessor does not prevent "Unknown column 'total_price'"

Comment: Are the queries on associative content or the origin model? If the origin model, I think you could add a scope; otherwise I've got another method you could use

Comment: It's on the origin model. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Will write an answer (too big for comments)

Answer (score 2):

Well we wanted to get `caption` (from join model) to appear on our associated `image` model (I.E if you called `@user.images`, you'd be able to call `image.caption` (even though caption was in the join model)

So we looked at [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins) (you'll benefit from around 6:40) which gave us some information about how you can use `join` to create more dynamic queries. We ended up using this:

```
has_many :images, -> { select("#{Image.table_name}.*, #{ImageMessage.table_name}.caption AS caption") }
```

I'm thinking you could use something similar for your request (include some SQL to create the pseudo column in the object). Since it's the origin model, I'm thinking about a scope like this:

```
default_scope select("(table.quantity * table.price) as total_price")
```

Comment: I honestly don't see the value in this, since now you'll have to write custom SQL for every query. Probably adds more to mantaince costs than it saves.

Comment: Thanks! It's really close to what I was expected. But I'm still unable to do `Order.sum(:total_price)`. Any idea on this?

Comment: @FarleyKnight, I only posted as a suggestion - it works for one of our apps; whether it translates is another story ^_^ And plus, if we can get it working for the OP, we can refactor later

Comment: @Such does ActiveRecord return a `total_price` attribute now?

Comment: @RichPeck Yes it does!

Comment: Hmmmm let me have a little think for you

Comment: From what I can see, this is creating an [`alias`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) in SQL. It would be very helpful if you could post your query for the scope (the select query) & then the query for the (sum query). @FarleyKnight will probably be able to share about this more than me, but it might be to do with how ActiveRecord fires the Model.sum() function

Comment: Also, perhaps we could use the sum method on the previously-created ActiveRecord object -- like `@order.sum(:total_price)`

Comment: I'm going to leave experience to be a better teacher than my ability communicate. Come back in a year or two, after using these types of queries, and report on what the best solution is.

Comment: sum query: `SELECT SUM(total_price) AS sum_id FROM orders` -
select query: `SELECT (orders.quantity * orders.price) as total_price FROM orders` -
Active record does not use the alias for the sum...
FYI `Order.pluck(:revenue).sum` does not work as well...

Comment: @Such did you try performing `@order.sum(:total_price)`? I'll take another look at the documentation for this in a second

Answer (score -1):

I assume price is stored in the database. Is quantity stored in the database? If both are stored, why not make `total_price` a database column as well? You can update `total_price` whenever you update the record.'

```
class Order < AR::Base
  before_update :update_total_price
  def update_total_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * price
  end
end
```

Obviously you can do anything you would with an ordinary column, like `Order.where("total_price > 1.0")` and what-not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That might be a solution indeed but that's what I would call denormalization. I was wondering if there was a solution that did not imply adding a column to my database.

Comment: Denormalization is for huge databases that support megacorporations, not startup projects written by a Rails app.

Comment: In Donald Knuth's paper "StructuredProgrammingWithGoToStatements", he wrote: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: I'm just looking for the rails best practices here. It it implies adding a column so be it. I was just wondering if there was another way. And adding a column to store a precomputed result might as well be seen as premature optimization don't you think ?

Comment: I've been doing Rails for almost 8 years. There is no built-in Rails best practice for ORM-layer virtual columns. Implementing one would be, in this case, the premature optimization, not storing the precomputed value.

Comment: This is probably the best you'll get, but it's still a precomputed value under the hood: https://github.com/bebanjo/persistize

Comment: The value is precomputed and saved before update here: https://github.com/bebanjo/persistize/blob/master/lib/persistize.rb#L26

Comment: I'm sorry I keep insisting because it's not that straight forward for me to precompute the column. I don't have all the information I need at the same time (actually the formula is more complex than what I wrote in my question) and I don't want the last update with the last piece of information to trigger a huge update on the precomputed column.

Comment: If it's not that straight forward, than it sounds like you're going to need to ask for more time to complete tasks around that code. The best practice for computed columns is evident in the Rails code itself. See how counter_cache is implemented. They add another column and update the column as the association is updated: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast

Comment: The answer and comments in this suggest doing things that are generally bad practices -- writing code like this will not scale in a high-volumbe Production environment. I am downvoting for that reason

Comment: Farley- there's a reason that "megacorporations" as you say denormalize and optimize, it's because they are operating at scale. Coding the way you suggest here is very costly not right for a company preparing for significant traffic.

Comment: Since writing my original answer, I'm actually working for a large company that does Rails apps (namely Bloomberg). We have lots of programmers who handle database normalization at the service layer with C++, while the Rails stuff is handled by app developers.